# Kona Honzo ESD + Bafang BBSHD?

Tags: electric-bike

My dream build would be the Honzo ESD with the BBSHD but before I pull the trigger on buying the frame (I plan to go 42t Bling Ring or an Eclipse ring with 8 or 9 speed cassette) , is there any issues you could see arising like intrusive chainstays? The frame bottom bracket is threaded 73mm and its an overbuilt steel hardtail so it should hold up well with the motor/battery. I have already bought the BBSHD 68mm mid drive. Thanks

Comment: Nice! Did you ever make the build and how did it work out..?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply!! I had to put the whole build on pause for a long while but I'm back at it now. I ended up getting the Stanton Sherpa hardtail frame, Rockshox Pike forks, DT Swiss H 1900 wheels and am currently working on finding the ideal rear derailleur then its all ready to be assembled. I hope everything fits together, kinda nervous about that